# How to hide browser's scrollbar when using locomotive-scroll in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, locomotive-scroll

I've been trying to use locomotive-scroll to add the smooth scrolling feature to my website. I got it up and running well, however while scrolling, I notice that the browser's default scrollbar stays at the same place as the scrollbar from the locomotive-scroll. I tried to do everything to hide it but no success. Can anyone instruct me on this issue. Thank you. Here is the image of the scrollbar (the pink part is the locomotive's scrollbar).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hide scrollbar function and add it to the pages you are using locomotive scroll.

Example:

```
function HideBrowserScrollbar() {
  let scrollHide = document.createElement("style");
  scrollHide.innerHTML = `body::-webkit-scrollbar {display: none;}`;
  document.head.appendChild(scrollHide);
}
```